# How to change html table cell type

Tags: html

I have a table in html to store a particular category and names associated with that category. Here is my code-

```
<table border ="1" width="30%">
 <tr>
    <td><em>Category</em></td>
    <td><em>People</em></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Cars</td>
    <td>John Smith</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

My question is- is it possible to make the second column in the table into a listbox/ combo box field to store multiple values, so that more than one person can be associated with each category without having to enter the category name more than once? Totally new to html so any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you can use the select tag within the td tag.

```
<table border ="1" width="30%">
   <tr>
      <td><em>Category</em></td>
      <td><em>People</em></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Cars</td>
      <td>
          <select id="sPeople">
             <option>John Smith</option>
             <option>Ali Chang</option>
             <option>David Alexander</option>
          </seclect>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```